# How do I add a condition to an array lookup?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, array-formulas

```
=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($E$2:E="foo"),$F$2:F)),"")

=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($E$2:E="foo",$a$2:a="bar"),$F$2:$F)),"")
```

The first snippet is finding the last entry in column F where Column E="foo"

The second snippet I am trying to add another condition that column A="bar" but its throwing errors.

Comment: you should use the multiplication operator `*` to combine the conditions.

Comment: like `=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2, 1/((E$2:E="foo")*(A$2:A="bar")), F$2:F))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate an AND, you have to multiply the conditions.

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(LOOKUP(2,1/((E2:E="foo")*(A2:A="bar")),F2:F))
```

Or you can simply use FILTER combined with CHOOSEROWS.

```cpp
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(F2:F,A2:A="bar",E2:E="foo"),-1)
```